# How to create multiple meta fields in gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I need to create a wordpress Gutenberg block that will allow me to insert some data as name and surname, company name, the best sentence from the references.

So far I managed to create a Gutenberg block that is saving one text field.

dc-references-block.php

```
// register custom meta tag field
function dcr_register_post_meta() {
    register_post_meta( 'page', 'dc_references_block_field', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'dcr_register_post_meta' );


function dcr_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'dc-references-block-script',
        plugins_url( 'dc-references-block.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-components' )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'dcr_enqueue' );
```

dc-references-block.js

```
( function( wp ) {
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    var TextControl = wp.components.TextControl;


    registerBlockType( 'dc-references-block/dc-references-block', {
        title: 'Title',
        icon: 'edit',
        category: 'common',

        attributes: {
            blockValue: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'meta',
                meta: 'dc_references_block_field'
            }
        },

        edit: function( props ) {
            var className = props.className;
            var setAttributes = props.setAttributes;

            function updateBlockValue( blockValue ) {
                setAttributes({ blockValue });
            }

            return el(
                'div',
                { className: className },
                el( TextControl, {
                    label: 'write here name of company',
                    value: props.attributes.blockValue,
                    onChange: updateBlockValue
                }
              )

            );
        },

        save: function() {
            return null;
        }
    } );
} )( window.wp );
```

Whenever I try to add a second text field or textarea to the block I get an error "site does not support this block".

Could anyone explain to me how to, in this situation, add correctly more then one text field and textarea to a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better if you included the code that did not work. In any case, I changed your code by adding another text input and a textarea (with relevant entries in attributes and meta).

Here is the modified code. Also, I have changed some of the code to be more readable.

### Javascript

```
( function( wp ) {
    const el = wp.element.createElement;
    const registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    const TextControl = wp.components.TextControl;
    const TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl;

    registerBlockType( 'dc-references-block/dc-references-block', {
        title: 'Title',
        icon: 'edit',
        category: 'common',

        attributes: {
            blockValue: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'meta',
                meta: 'dc_references_block_field'
            },
            // Add two new attributes
            name: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'meta',
                meta: 'dc_references_block_field_name'
            },
            desc: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'meta',
                meta: 'dc_references_block_field_desc'
            }
        },

        edit: function( props ) {
            const className = props.className;
            const setAttributes = props.setAttributes;

            // Original element with onChange event as an anonymous function
            const text = el( TextControl, {
                label: 'write here name of company',
                value: props.attributes.blockValue,
                key: 'companyName',
                onChange: function( value ) {
                    setAttributes( { name: value } );
                }
            } );

            //Add two new elements
            const secondText = el( TextControl, {
                label: 'Write your name',
                value: props.attributes.name,
                key: 'username',
                onChange: function( value ) {
                    setAttributes( { name: value } );
                }
            } );

            const textArea = el( TextareaControl, {
                label: 'Write a description',
                value: props.attributes.desc,
                key: 'desc',
                onChange: function( value ) {
                    setAttributes( { desc: value } );
                }
            } );

            return el(
                'div',
                { className: className },
                // Children of the main div as an array
                [ text, secondText, textArea ]
            );
        },

        save: function() {
            return null;
        }
    } );
}( window.wp ) );
```

### PHP

```
register_post_meta( 'page', 'dc_references_block_field', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
    ) );

   // register two new meta corresponding to attributes in JS
    register_post_meta( 'page', 'dc_references_block_field_name', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
    ) );

    register_post_meta( 'page', 'dc_references_block_field_desc', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
    ) );
```

Comment: I have one more question. Is there a way to show the block only for a specific custom field ?

Comment: I don't follow. Do you mean multiple inputs for one custom field?

Comment: before gutenberg by adding a meta box you could decide if its going to be displayed in admin panel for post, page or custom post by `add_meta_box( 'name_meta_box', // $id  'title', // $title  'show_name_meta_box', // $callback  'custom-post-name', // $screen  'normal', // $context  'high' // $priority);` is this still possible?

Comment: Gutenberg blocks are dependent on user interaction. They only show if the user adds them. Metabox show regardless. If you want the user to be able to select the block only in page screen you see this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/243738/35871